# Resource File Links

Tags: silverlight, resources, hyperlink, wcf-ria-services, business-application

When you create a Silverlight Business Application you get a Silverlight application and a Web application. In the Web/Resources folder of the Silverlight app there are links to the files in the Resources folder of the Web app. These links are exactly like the files they link to in that they are heirarchical with the Resource.Designer.cs file shown as a code-behind file for the Resource.resx file

When I try to link to a Resource file in this way I only get the .resx file unless I link to the .Designer.cs file separately. However in this case the Designer.cs file is then shown as a standard code file and not related to the .resx file.

Does anyone know how to do this linking correctly?

Comment: I just tried to remove a .cs file on one of the existing linked resources and then added it again. Then it was shown inline with the .resx file instead of in a heirarchi.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After you add a link to new resource file without *.Designer.cs, set its property "Custom Tool" ("PublicResXFileCodeGenerator").